# Cannot connect HDP 2.6 Sandbox in virtual box with Bridged Network

Tags: hadoop, networking, virtualbox

The Issue am facing with is critical and stopping my entire work.
I downloaded the HDP 2.6 and installed on Virtual Box in NAT. My host machine is Ubentu.

So am trying to ping from Host to Guest machine through NAT (ie.,from Ubentu to CentOS ) I could not able to Ping. then through Web Crawling i came to know Bridged Network in Vbox can help. So i switched from NAT to Bridged Network in the Vbox. But the Sandbox is unable to open in Bridged Network and throwing the network connectivity issue. And Also i came to know Port Forwarding can help in resolving the issue, but could not find the detailed notes on that.

Conclusion: I want to ping from both the machines ie., (guest to host and host to guest in bridged network for Vbox) i was able to add the ip address in the /etc/hosts file. So on top of that i want to build 3 node cluster setup once i find the solution to run the sandbox 2.6 on bridged network on virualbox

Comment: Even if it's critical for you, it would be good form to adhere to the site guidelines. Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions. Maybe ask on our sister site [su]? But check their guidelines (too) first.

Answer (score 0):

The HDP sandbox already comes with all the necessary ports forwarded in the VirtualBox network adapter settings. For example, [SSH is running on port 2222](https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/learning-the-ropes-of-the-hortonworks-sandbox/#environment-setup).

Ping is not addressable over one of those ports, and you shouldn't need it to use any of the Hadoop services

If you want to build a 3 node cluster, you should not be using the sandbox, though. Rather 3 blank VM's that you [use Ambari to provision them all](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.6.1.0/bk_ambari-installation/content/ch_Getting_Ready.html)

Comment: Ping uses ICMP, which doesn't use ports. Ports are addresses for _some_ transport protocols (UDP and TCP), but other transport procols use other addressing, or no addressing at all.